# Exceptions propagating from unmanaged code to managed code?

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I have a chunk of unmanaged C++ code I am reusing on a C# project.  The unmanaged C++ code is wrapped inside a layer of managed C++ code, which interacts with the C# code.  Right now, the unmanaged C++ code uses assert(false) to raise critical errors.  Since assert() writes to stderr and my project is a GUI program I don't think the assert printouts will show up.  I'm thinking of replacing the assert(false) with throw new exception(...) and then catch and display the exceptions at the C# GUI layer.  My questions are:

1) Is replacing assert() with exception() a good idea? if not why?

2) If exceptions are thrown inside unmanaged C++ code, will they propagate properly to the managed C++ and then to C# code (with the stack trace intact and correct)?

Thanks,

Comment: Using [`assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx) as an error handler was a bad idea in the first place. It has no effect if `NDEBUG` is defined. `assert` will write to `stderr` in a console application and call `MessageBox` in a GUI application. This will be visible (in debug builds anyway).

Comment: @llnspectable  yes I know about assert being compiled out in release build.  I'm sort of OK with that.  My most important concern is getting a stack trace when errors occur.  assert only writes to stderr which a GUI program doesn't have so that is the bigger drawback for me.

Comment: The default behavior of assert() is to invoke a debugger break.  Don't mess with that.

Comment: @Hans The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx) disagrees with your statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Is replacing assert() with exception() a good idea? if not why?

[`assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4.aspx) is a debugging tool. It will evaluate to a no-op in a release build and is not meant to be used as an error handling facility. Implementing an error reporting system based on exceptions is the natural thing to do in C++.

> 2) If exceptions are thrown inside unmanaged C++ code, will they propagate properly to the managed C++ and then to C# code (with the stack trace intact and correct)?

C++ exceptions thrown in native code will be converted to [SEHException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception.aspx)s when tavelling from unmanaged to managed code. C++ exceptions can be handled in native code, in a C++/CLI interop layer or in managed code. (Human readable) call stack information is not available in native code.

---

Background information on exception handling in a mixed mode environment:

C++ exceptions (as implement in Microsoft's C++ compiler) as well as exceptions in the CLR are built on top of SEH Exceptions. [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx) is a service built into Windows that can be consumed by any environment that can interface with C. Sharing the same foundation enables exceptions to seamlessly propagate from managed to unmanaged code and vice versa.

All SEH exceptions carry the same information stored in an [`EXCEPTION_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082.aspx). The `ExceptionAddress` member is used as the entry point in constructing a stack trace. Managed assemblies contain enough meta data to construct a human readable stack trace. Native executable images on the other hand do not. While it is possible to produce a stack trace (using [`StackWalk64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650.aspx), for example) no symbolic information will be included unless the respective debugging information (.pdb) is available.

---

Alternatives to a stack trace:

While a stack trace may give you a few hints where an exception was raised it does not contain any more helpful information for debugging, such as parameters and locals. An alternative would be to write a minidump instead. [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) is an immensely powerful tool to do so, giving you very fine grained control over which data should be included. A very good introduction can be found at [Effective Minidumps - Part 1](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html) and [Effective Minidumps - Part 2](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps2.html). Minidumps can be loaded into a debugger (such as Visual Studio or WinDBG) and analyzed. With matching debugging symbols (which you should add to your source control system for any release) you get an insanely effective infrastructure for analyzing problems. Depending on the minidump information available you will get the call stacks for all threads, parameters passed to functions, contents of locals, loaded and unloaded modules, etc.

Comment: @llnspectable  thanks for the detailed info!  I especially like the minidump suggestion.  Will definitely look into it.  One question on assert: per Microsoft documentation if assert is called from a Windows-based application it will show the message in a messagebox. But what if assert is called from deep inside a DLL that is linked into a Windows-based application, will a messagebox still be used?

Comment: @llnspectable - is it better to create a minidump at the point the fatal error occurs or let it throw an exception and catch it at the highest level and then do a minidump there?  The advantage to the latter is I don't have to sprinkle minidump calls throughout the entire codebase.  Just wondering if there is any disadvantage that way.

Comment: @Thomas The `assert` implementation evaluates an (undocumented) `__app_type` variable declared in the CRT so it will always choose the correct output method. You should always write a minidump immediately when an exception is raised, to get the relevant call stack. For this you need to install an SEH exception filter (which will get you the `EXCEPTION_RECORD` required for `MiniDumpWriteDump`). This lets you handle all exceptions in a single place - no need to sprinkle calls throughout your code. It's not exactly trivial, and you should probably ask a new question about this topic.

Comment: MSDN link: [Structured Exception Handling (C/C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx)